# How does module dependency work in Android?

Tags: android, makefile

I made minor changes to su-binary (https://github.com/git-core/su-binary) adding a target to set SUID.
The Android.mk I use : http://pastebin.com/N0gMJT4u
When running make at the root of Android source tree, things run fine:

```
$ make -j5
[...]
system/core/rootdir/Android.mk:42: warning: ignoring old commands for target `out/target/product/panda/root/init.rc'
echo "Setting SUID/GUID to su-binary"
Setting SUID/GUID to su-binary
Installing busybox
chmod ug+s out/target/product/panda/system/xbin/su
[...]
```

When running `mm -B` in external/su-binary: http://pastebin.com/8HmUJBA0
Same behavior for `mmm external/su-binary`

According to https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/android-building/dtNZFj5pe1w/PRY2MXADXG4J

> Apart from "make name-of-module" as suggested by Ying Wang, you can
>   run "mm" inside a directory to build (and install) all modules defined
>   there. However, this will build *only* those modules, any dependent
>   modules will *not* be built. Hence, it's only useful for incremental
>   builds of existing trees where you keep track of the dependencies.

Tried that:

```
$ rm out/target/product/panda/system/xbin/su
$ make external/su-binary
[...]
make: Nothing to be done for `external/su-binary'.

$ rm out/target/product/panda/obj/EXECUTABLES/su_intermediates/su
$ make external/su-binary
[...]
make: Nothing to be done for `external/su-binary`.
```

How does module dependency work in Android?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I got it running by changing the Android.mk:

1. name the `$(SU_BINARY)` target differently, ie `$(SU_BINARY)-post`. Better because before, it has the same name as the target defined by the `LOCAL_MODULE` and `BUILD_EXECUTABLE` combination.
2. put this target before the `include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)`

It looks like:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := su
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := su.c db.c activity.cpp

SU_SHARED_LIBRARIES := liblog libsqlite
ifeq ($(PLATFORM_SDK_VERSION),4)
    LOCAL_CFLAGS += -DSU_LEGACY_BUILD
    SU_SHARED_LIBRARIES += libandroid_runtime
else
    SU_SHARED_LIBRARIES += libcutils libbinder libutils
    LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := eng
endif

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += external/sqlite/dist

LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := $(SU_SHARED_LIBRARIES)

LOCAL_MODULE_PATH := $(TARGET_OUT_OPTIONAL_EXECUTABLES)


SU_INSTALL_DIR := $(TARGET_OUT)/xbin
SU_BINARY := $(SU_INSTALL_DIR)/su
# taken from busybox-android
$(SU_BINARY)-post: su
    @echo "Setting SUID/GUID to su-binary..."
    chmod ug+s $(TARGET_OUT_OPTIONAL_EXECUTABLES)/su
    ln -sf $(TARGET_OUT_OPTIONAL_EXECUTABLES)/su $(TARGET_OUT_EXECUTABLES)/su

ALL_DEFAULT_INSTALLED_MODULES += $(SU_BINARY)-post

include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
```

`ALL_DEFAULT_INSTALLED_MODULES` is a rule coming very late after module installation I think. But I got to dig into it to check if that's the best solution for what I want to do here.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to let us know the answer

Comment: hi m-ric, i wanted to discuss a similar issue with u!! Can we talk??

Comment: @Neji push your question with code sample on SO. There are great chances you'll get an answer quickly.